# I want to retrieve all user's UID from Firebase user array and store it into Arraylist

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    databaseReference.child("user").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

           for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String requests = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                req.add(requests);
                adapter = new ChallengeSuggestionAdapter(getActivity(), req);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
```

Thanks for helping :)

[image: All the unique Id in user array]

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're recreating the adapter within the loop. Don't do that.

```
final List<String> req = new ArrayList<>();
final ChallengeSuggestionAdapter adapter = new ChallengeSuggestionAdapter(getActivity(), req);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

databaseReference.child("user").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
       req.clear();
       for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String requests = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            req.add(requests);
        }
        recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Also, I don't think `getValue(String.class)` is correct, but you've not expanded your Firebase nodes, so hard to say.

If you want that UUID, you would use `req.add(postSnapshot.getKey())`

Answer (score 1):

Create GenericTypeIndicator to pass value from DataSnapshot.getValue() parameter.

Look:-

```
GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> typeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};

List<String> stringArrary = dataSnapshot.getValue(typeIndicator );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Use getKey if you want the uid and take your recyclerview adapter from the loop. try using addValueEventListener


    databaseReference.child("user").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                req.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String requests = postSnapshot.getKeyString.class);
            req.add(requests);
        }
       adapter = new ChallengeSuggestionAdapter(getActivity(), req);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    }
                                });
```